# Question and answer using a mathematical book

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In the help section, it states that it is encouraged to post Q & A. However I do not want to go about it the wrong way.

Basically I am attempting exercises in Kaplansky's book *Set Theory And Metric Spaces*. I wanted to post the question, and post the answer myself with an elaborate proof. I would then want comments on how structured my proof is and what can be improved from it.

The other option is to just post my attempt in the question box, and ask what can be improved.

Which one of these options is recommended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way of asking "check my proof" questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions).

Comment: In this particular context, I'd say that answering the questions in a proper answer would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 8):

I think there's a simple answer to this question:

> *Answers go in the answer box.*

If your question is *How's my proof?*, then your proof is not an answer to that question.  In this case, I think it'd be better in the question.  (Your question suggests this is the case.)

If you have a proof but want to learn about other proofs, then you have an answer to the question *What's a proof for this?*  In this case, I think it'd be better as an answer.  Oh, and a little warning in this case:

> "A slight problem is that an attempted proof is more likely to be wrong and therefore to attract downvotes." -- [Michael Greinecker](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5026/139).

Comment: The [tag:alternative-proof] tag comes to mind.

Comment: Regarding to the quote by Michael: if one is concerned with downvotes (to one's reputation), would it be okay to post the attempted answer to one's _own_ question as CW answer? Or would it be frowned upon by the community? Just curious :)

Comment: I think it would be a great idea to make the attempted answer a CW...